# How to regex this?

Tags: regex, vb.net, match

Hello I'm trying to get a mass type of href into a listbox. Anyone know what's the regex match to get only that thing after href?

Here is a line from multiple ones which I'm trying to optain:

```
<a class="streamItemsAge" data-hint="January 13, 2016 12:15:31 GMT" href="/Game/player/19928271">yesterday</a>
```

Here is my code:

```
        Dim pp As String = textbox1.text
    Dim strRegex As String = "GMT"" <?href\s*=\s*[""'].+?[""'][^>]*?"
    Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None)
    For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(pp)
        If myMatch.Success Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(myMatch)
        End If
    Next
```

Note: data-hint value will be different for each href, so I'm really confused. Please help me.

This will be the output: /Game/player/19928271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim pp As String = textbox1.text
    Dim strRegex As String = "data-hint.+href=""([^""]+)"""
    Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None)
    For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(pp)
        If myMatch.Success Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(myMatch.Groups(1).Value)
        End If
    Next
```

Just adjusted Filepe's answer and stuck it in your code. Should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The regex below capture the content inside href=""

```
href="([^"]+)"
```

Explanation:

- href=" matches the characters href=" literally
- () is the capturing group
- [^"]+ match any character until find the character "
- " matches the character " literally

You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/hM3sG4/1)

Comment: Yes it works, but just to math that type of line. When I use this every link after href including the right ones will appear in listbox and I don't want this. I just want that type of links.

Comment: What kind of link? you mean /Game/player/ ? .. If so just change the regex to `href="(\/Game\/player\/[^"]+)"`